# Sparkline in Google Sheets shows errors with options

Tags: google-sheets, sparklines

I am trying to get some graphs via googlefinance in my sheets.

```
=SPARKLINE(GoogleFinance(A4; "price"; TODAY()-180; TODAY()))
```

works totally fine but

```
=SPARKLINE(GOOGLEFINANCE(A4,"price", TODAY()-30,TODAY()),{"charttype","line";"color","green"})
```

gives me parsing errors. If I try it in another sheet, it works.

Comment: both formulae works. what says the error? share a copy of your sheet.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KPo15Fv9B4fzFA31EvwTCjY24iI9DeHdKq2g4Xk3WmY/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your sheet is german so you need to use:

```
; insted of , in formulas

\ instead of , in arrays {}
```

so formula will be:

```
=SPARKLINE(GOOGLEFINANCE(A4; "price"; TODAY()-30; TODAY());
 {"charttype"\"line";"color"\"green"})
```

[image]