# Sparkline formula parse error (not locale)

Tags: google-sheets, sparklines

I'm getting "formula parse error" for the following formula in Google Sheets:

```
=SPARKLINE(D3,{“charttype”,“bar”;“max”,MAX($D$3:$D$69)})
```

I'm in the US, so this fits the US syntax. To no avail, I tried the EU syntax \ and ; described in other answers to this topic, like:

[Sparkline in Google Sheets shows errors with options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66242923/sparkline-in-google-sheets-shows-errors-with-options)

I'm following the Google documentation as well as a couple of tutorials I read on this formula, so I'm not sure why it's not working. The data I'm pulling from are static values, but I also tried using it with a SORT formula pulling data from another sheet (which is ultimately what I want). For that I did try pulling the data directly from the original sheet instead of the sorted sheet:

```
=SPARKLINE(vlookup(A3,'Chicken Coops'!A3:D69,4),{“charttype”,“bar”;“max”,MAX('Chicken Coops'!A3:D69)})
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

issue most likely with the incompatible double quotes used within. try:

`=SPARKLINE(vlookup(A3,'Chicken Coops'!A3:D69,4),{"charttype","bar";"max",MAX('Chicken Coops'!A3:D69)})`

Comment: Ah, yes. Why is it always so easy to overlook the simplest solution? Just a matter of copying/pasting from the web. Those nasty HTML quotes. Thanks!